# Cant get canvas strokestyle to work

Tags: html, canvas

I am using the following code to draw in a html5 canvas but the storkeStyle do not work.
I see that in the console that the this.color is changed but its keeping to draw with the same color as it was orignal set at. (it is updating when mouse is moved).

```
    ctx.lineWidth = pixelRatio * this.lineThickness;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + this.color[0] + "," + this.color[1] + "," + this.color[2] + "," + this.color[3] + ")";
    ctx.beginPath()
    //ctx.beginPath();
    //Horizontal
    ctx.moveTo(pos[0] * pixelRatio, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(pos[0] * pixelRatio, (pos[1] - squareSize2) * pixelRatio);
    ctx.moveTo(pos[0] * pixelRatio, (pos[1] + squareSize2) * pixelRatio);
    ctx.lineTo(pos[0] * pixelRatio, frameState.size[1] * pixelRatio);


    //Vertical
    ctx.moveTo(0, pos[1] * pixelRatio);
    ctx.lineTo((pos[0] - squareSize2) * pixelRatio, pos[1] * pixelRatio);
    ctx.moveTo((pos[0] + squareSize2) * pixelRatio, pos[1] * pixelRatio);
    ctx.lineTo(frameState.size[0] * pixelRatio, pos[1] * pixelRatio);


    ctx.rect((pos[0] - squareSize) * pixelRatio, (pos[1] - squareSize) * pixelRatio, squareSize2 * pixelRatio, squareSize2 * pixelRatio);


    ctx.moveTo((pos[0] - squareSize4) * pixelRatio, pos[1] * pixelRatio);
    ctx.lineTo((pos[0] + squareSize4) * pixelRatio, pos[1] * pixelRatio);


    ctx.moveTo(pos[0] * pixelRatio, (pos[1] - squareSize4) * pixelRatio);
    ctx.lineTo(pos[0] * pixelRatio, (pos[1] + squareSize4) * pixelRatio);

    console.log("rgba(" + this.color[0] + "," + this.color[1] + "," + this.color[2] + "," + this.color[3] + ")");

    ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Your `ctx.strokeStyle` works fine (assuming your this.colors are values from 0-255):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/zLr5ajey/

Comment: its working initially, but when updated in a loop its not recoloring.  (the app is in openlayers3 so was alittle hard to get it all into fiddle)

Comment: Then your issue is with code outside of the code you've presented above. ;-)

Comment: i cant see how your example shows that. Your example shows exactly the same as i am getting in the application. That it colors by the correct color on first draw, but in the next draws it stay the same color. But sure, i will wrap up a full example soon

Answer (score -1):

THe issue was that i had floating point values in the color and it only worked when values had no decimal points.